# Apollo Network (Bad Request) error not caught in apollo-link-error

Tags: meteor, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js, apollo-boost

Sending a mutation with a bad set of variables (on purpose in this case) results in errors being thrown in the console, and the apollo-link-error link not picking up the error.  Additionally, the mutation loading state is stuck as 'loading' and not error object comes through.

Through a debugging session, I fount that the zen-observable global error handling picks up an error thrown in the error-link's "next" function, because 'result' is not defined

pasted the apollo-link-error code that has the observable wrapped in a try catch, but the catch at the bottom here is not the catch that gets hit when `if (result.errors)` throws a 'nullpointer' because result in undefined.

````js
    try {
                    sub = forward(operation).subscribe({
                        next: function (result) {
                            // result is undefined, throwing an error
                            if (result.errors) {
                                retriedResult = errorHandler({
                                    graphQLErrors: result.errors,
                                    response: result,
                                    operation: operation,
                                    forward: forward,
                                });
                                if (retriedResult) {
                                    retriedSub = retriedResult.subscribe({
                                        next: observer.next.bind(observer),
                                        error: observer.error.bind(observer),
                                        complete: observer.complete.bind(observer),
                                    });
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                            observer.next(result);
                        },
                        error: function (networkError) {
                            retriedResult = errorHandler({
                                operation: operation,
                                networkError: networkError,
                                graphQLErrors: networkError &&
                                    networkError.result &&
                                    networkError.result.errors,
                                forward: forward,
                            });
                            if (retriedResult) {
                                retriedSub = retriedResult.subscribe({
                                    next: observer.next.bind(observer),
                                    error: observer.error.bind(observer),
                                    complete: observer.complete.bind(observer),
                                });
                                return;
                            }
                            observer.error(networkError);
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            if (!retriedResult) {
                                observer.complete.bind(observer)();
                            }
                        },
                    });
                } // the error is NOT caught here
                catch (e) {
                    errorHandler({ networkError: e, operation: operation, forward: forward });
                    observer.error(e);
                }
    ```

Link definition:
```javascript

    export const client = new ApolloClient({
      link: ApolloLink.from([
        onError((errors) => {
          console.log('errors in link!', errors);
          handleServerError(errors);
        }),
        new MeteorAccountsLink(),
        new HttpLink({
          uri: '/graphql',
        }),
      ]),
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
````

Edit:
The request in the browser does show a response with an error object with the graphQlErro of shape `{errors: [{..}]}` which is strange that it's not coming into the 'result' in the link.

Edit 2:

It looks like Meteor is picking up the error thrown in the http link prior to the error posted above, which might be why "result" is undefined.  Writing a custom link to polyfill the missing 'result' so the app will at least work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an issue with Meteor swallowing the errors.  fixed make making a polyfill link to at least not break the js in the mutation complete function and show a general error.
`const stupidMeteorErorrPolyfill = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => forward(operation).map(data => data || { errors: [{ message: '! Empty response in gql links, see graphql.js and network tab' }] }));`